# how to set textwrapping property for combobox items in J2ME lwuit

Tags: java-me, lwuit, word-wrap

I am using lwuit `ComboBox`.

I have to set multiline with textwrapping property for `ComboBox` items. If the size of the item is bigger than the `ComboBox` width, the text have to wrap to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to `derive` the `ComboBox` class and implement the protected method `createPopupList()` where you add a `TextArea` field into the `List`.

Comment: Thank you can you plz provide any link or sample code for your suggestion